# JDY-16 Bluetooth Rx/Tx Connection

Tags: bluetooth, connect

How i can make jdy-16 to arduino rx/tx connection? http://prntscr.com/k4dmqg

01 pin > VCC
24 pin > GND
19 pin > TX
20 pin > RX

But device doesn't answer AT COMMANDS!

When i connect jdy-16 with mobile apps, i can give connection and disconnection message on arduino ide. So it's say, your connection is correct.

But at commands doesn't work.

I tried port 5,21 to GND but didn't work.

JDY-16 Datasheet > http://shop.cpu.com.tw/upload/2017/11/BT-JDY16-2.pdf

Thanks.

Comment: Confirm the AT commands have the proper terminator.  Page 10 of the datasheet: "Special note: JDY-16 module serial port instruction AT need to add terminator \r\n".

Comment: when i selected both nl & cr then it's worked. Thanks.

Comment: if you think the response below is sufficient, please mark it as  an 'accepted answer' so this question is listed as solved.

Comment: i didn't find 'accepted answer' button, sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

AT commands for the JDY-16 require '\r\n' termination.

- '\r' = Carriage Return character (0x0D).
- '\n' = Line Feed character (0x0A).

From page 10 of the datasheet:

> "Special note: JDY-16 module serial port instruction AT need to add
>   terminator \r\n".